# How does a vpn connection work?

Tags: computer-networks, security, network-topology

I have been looking into vpn (virtual private network). And I wanted to know more about the theory, how does it work really:

- what does it do with the packages?
- why is it secure? (or why can it be unsecure)
- how does it work on the internet?
- how can it simulate you're coming from another country?

It feels so mainstream nowadays (sole available directly from the browser), that I wanted to understand better what happens when you use one.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is on-topic here, but an interesting question nonetheless.